# How to use Bootstrap 3 popover with relative position in normal document flow?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to use a Bootstrap 3 popover as a relatively positioned element that is inserted in normal document flow, so it pushes down the subsequent DOM elements. That is, I have a big image at the top, followed by a form. When the image is clicked, I want a popover to appear below the image, pushing down the form.

I understand that popovers generally have an absolute position as in the normal use case this makes sense. However, in my particular case, I'd like it to be relatively positioned, but still appear below the element it belongs to. Is there a (non-hacky) way to accomplish this?

Comment: Something can be a block element *and* positioned absolutely. They are defined by two different properties, I.E. `display:block` and `position:absolute`.

Comment: True that, I edited my question accordingly

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple CSS to override Bootstrap's `position:absolute`..

```
.popover {
    position:relative;
}
```

Demo: http://www.bootply.com/129257

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use the popover for this? Seems like you would be better served by the collapse component: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse

And if you don't absolutely HAVE to use Bootsrap for this, jQuery's slideToggle function would accomplish what you're looking for, too: https://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/